# create vector of objects on the stack ? (c++)

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory

I am creating a temporary vector of pointers to `myObject` objects. But I am wondering about what happens to the objects I created...

```
{
    std::vector<myObject *> myVector;
    myVector.reserve(5);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i){
        myVector[i] = new myObject();
    }
}
```

I assume that at the end of the scope `myVector` is destroyed and all the pointers with it, but as I created the objects with the keyword `new`, does it means that those objects still exist somewhere on the heap ? Should I destroy them manually before the end of the scope ?

Comment: Change `myVector.reserve(5);` to `myVector.resize(5);`
`

Comment: And yes, you need to delete `myObject` instances you have created with `new`.

Comment: thanks all for your clear answers ! :) (I still don't understand why this question is downvoted... Is that not clear enough ? I don't think that was a silly question...)

Comment: _"I still don't understand why this question is downvoted ..."_ Missing [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), wrong use of `std::vector::reserve()` (leads to UB), low research efforts about the topic. These were my reasons at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those objects still exist and you must delete them.

Alternatively you could use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myObject>>` instead, so that your objects are `delete`d automatically.

Or you could just not use dynamic allocation as it is more expensive and error-prone.

Also note that you are misusing `reserve`. You either want to use `resize`, or `reserve` paired with `push_back`.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the following

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myObject>> myVector(5);
for (auto& obj : myVector)
{
    obj = std::make_unique<myObject>();
}
```

This will create your vector with size `5`, instead of you having to resize it afterwards. On that note, you would have had to do so with `resize` instead of `reserve`.

If your vector is of `std::unique_ptr`, then you don't have to worry about memory management, the pointers will clean themselves up when the vector falls out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: You Need to destroy every object you created with `new`!

This means, your objects are not destroyed, only the pointers.
You Need to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i){
    delete myVector[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remember: each `new` should be 'paired' with `delete`.

So yes - those objects remain in the heap - you have a memory leak.

Either create a loop calling delete, or change type of vector to store `std::unique_ptr<myObject>` - this will delete pointers automatically.